# WPF Itemscontrol which fills all available space while child elements have the same size

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

i have a Grid with 2 columns, A and B. Column B contains an itemscontrol with a set number of items, lets say 20.

I want theese 20 items displayed horizontally, all items must have the same size and the available space must be filled like horizontalAlignment = Stretch.

I already tried the following without success:

- A grid with sharedgridSize and a columngroup - Items have the same size but only take the size they need i.e. do not fill the available space.
- A uniform grid: works like a charm, the problem is that the items that I want to display are displayed by an usercontrol which also contains a grid.. which is destroyed by the parent uniform grid.
- A listbox: same problem like the grid.

So my question is:

- Is there a WPF way to handle this problem without backend code?
- If its only possible with backend code, which is the best way if the itemscount is set and does not change, e.g. 20.

Comment: I think you should re-visit the `UniformGrid` approach and concentrate on *why is the inner `Grid` layout destroyed*.

Comment: From what i have read, the uniform grid is just programmed to take control over the layout.. So there is no way to add any further layout in child elements

Comment: No idea what you've read there, but it's wrong. You can of course nest Panels with different layout strategies.